# Python: access the value of a nested children in WaterML (xml) file with ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I want to access the values of a child in a WaterML file.

In [this](http://%3Chttps://hs-apps.hydroshare.org/apps/nwm-forecasts/api/GetWaterML/?archive=rolling&config=analysis_assim&geom=forcing&variable=SWDOWN&COMID=2236,1144&lon=-98&lat=38.5&startDate=2018-07-23&endDate=2018-07-25&time=00&lag=t00z%3E) WaterML file, a child called **values** has several children as **value**. For example, the first element in the **values** has the variable value of **506.351**. The problem is that I cannot access this value when using the below code in *Python*.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


url = https://hs-apps.hydroshare.org/apps/nwm-forecasts/api/GetWaterML/?archive=rolling&config=analysis_assim&geom=forcing&variable=SWDOWN&COMID=2236,1144&lon=-98&lat=38.5&startDate=2018-07-23&endDate=2018-07-25&time=00&lag=t00z

r = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
for child in root.iter('{http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.1/}value'):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

The output does not include the variable value (for example, 506.351)

I do appreciate any help or idea on how to access the variable values in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use child.text to extract text surrounded by value tag.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://hs-apps.hydroshare.org/apps/nwm-forecasts/api/GetWaterML/?archive=rolling&config=analysis_assim&geom=forcing&variable=SWDOWN&COMID=2236,1144&lon=-98&lat=38.5&startDate=2018-07-23&endDate=2018-07-25&time=00&lag=t00z'

requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
for child in root.iter('{http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.1/}value'):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib, child.text, '\n')
```

The output is:

```
{http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.1/}value {'censorCode': 'nc', 'dateTime': '2018-07-23T00:00:00', 'timeOffset': '0', 'dateTimeUTC': '2018-07-23T00:00:00', 'methodCode': '1', 'sourceCode': '1', 'qualityControlLevelCode': '1'} 506.351
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.